# Node.js Socket.io call a function from a different name space

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have 2 different name spaces i want in any way to call a function from another path i know its so weird but is there any way to do action from another path?
//Socket.io
Like i have functions **A** and **B** and **C**

I'm doing them on the client path

Now i want in the other path or name space to do `io.on(....)` inside it i wanna call A and B and C
It this functions or actions can't be anywhere else the client path... `</3` Any one can help please?

Example...

```
    io.of("something",async (req, res)=>{

        UpdateSomething(options,request_id); // Do here the actions inside this function in 
// in Client path io.of...

        });

    io.of("client",async (req, res)=>{

    function UpdateSomething(options,request_id){
                   //some query on mysql // insert data
                   let info_of_query_inserted_id = 1111;
                   //Some Actions...
                     //this info can't be out here or retrieve..
     }

    });
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you show with the code and a more explanation?

Comment: I'm sorry i knew it ill try wait me

Comment: In your client-side Javascript, you can call any client-side function from anywhere.  So, if A, B and C are just functions in your page's Javascript, you can call those functions from any event handler in that Javascript.  The part of your question that sounds like it may be confused is when you say you want to call a function from some other path.  If by "other path", you mean other page, then a page can only call functions that are within it's own page's Javascript.  You can't directly call functions in another page.  That other page might not even be active at the time.

Comment: When you use the term "namespace", are you talking about a actual socket.io namespace as the socket.io documentation uses the term?  Or are you just talking about the Javascript of a different page?

Comment: Oh yes socket.io name spaces i make edit on my question and put an example i'm really sorry for being not clear guys

Comment: Guys i'm trying to make queue for something like do something and when it finish do the next i don't know why i'm complicating it that much xdd any help?